Can vectors be made up of different functions as its components?
I was wondering if a vector can have its component as functions and whether those functions can be multivariable. The reason I am wondering this is because in economics as an example you might have a consumption vector representing different goods however that consumption might be based on different variables based on the good. From my understanding matrices can only do linear transformations, so if the consumption is not linear then the only way I can think to represent the difference in how the goods are consumed is based on other variables.
Added Explanation of Question:
Like I have taken linear algebra and Calc 3, but we never combined them in a way in which would show these function vector being used with linear algebra. So I suppose my question is rather whether you are able to use matrices with these functions to do linear transformations?

Look up "vector fields".

If you have a vector field over, say, the real numbers, then you can absolutely define a vector whose components are arbitrary functions, as long as those functions output real numbers - and we would call that a "vector-valued function". For example,
$$v(\theta) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$$
defines a vector-valued function from the real numbers to $\mathbb{R}^2$.
The only thing to be careful of is that linear transformations will not necessarily travel "through" the functions unscathed. By which I mean if you apply a linear transformation to $\theta$, it won't result in a linear transformation on $v$. For example, $v(\theta + \phi) = (\cos(\theta + \phi), \sin(\theta + \phi)) \neq v(\theta) + v(\phi)$.

Thanks, I think my confusion is about how these vectors might be used. Like I have taken linear algebra and Calc 3, but we never combined them in a way in which would show these function vector being used with linear algebra. So I suppose my question is rather whether you are able to use matrices with these functions to do linear transformations?

You can, if you're looking at linear combinations of those components. It becomes quite relevant when you start looking at vector calculus and so you can do things like look at the derivative of the dot product of vectors.
